# Holder inequality proof question

Tags: functional-analysis, inequality

I am just wondering how did we get this specific inequality less than or equal to $\frac{1}{p} + \frac{1}{q}$ ? Can someone explain that part?[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Shot in the dark...

$\sum_{j=1}^\infty \left(\frac{1}{p} \frac{|x_j|^p}{\|x\|_{\ell^p}^p}+\frac{1}{q} \frac{|y_j|^p}{\|y\|_{\ell^p}^p}\right) $

$= \frac{1}{p}\frac{\sum_{j=1}^\infty|x_j|^p}{\|x\|_{\ell^p}^p}+\frac{1}{q} \frac{\sum_{j=1}^\infty|y_j|^p}{\|y\|_{\ell^p}^p}$

$\leqslant \frac{1}{p}\frac{\sum_{j=1}^\infty|x_j|^p}{\|x\|_{\ell^p}^p}+\frac{1}{q} \frac{\sum_{j=1}^\infty|y_j|^p}{\|y\|_{\ell^p}^p}$

$ = \frac{1}{p}\frac{\|x\|_{\ell^p}^p}{\|x\|_{\ell^p}^p}+\frac{1}{q} \frac{\|y\|_{\ell^p}^p}{\|y\|_{\ell^p}^p}$

$ = \frac{1}{p} +\frac{1}{q}.$

Comment: haha very nice.. thank you..

Answer (score 0):

It's because

$$\sum_{j = 1}^n \frac{1}{p}\frac{\lvert x_j\rvert^p}{\|x\|_{\ell_p}^p} = \frac{1}{p\|x\|_{\ell_p}^p} \sum_{j = 1}^n \lvert x_j\rvert^p \le \frac{1}{p\|x\|_{\ell_p}^p} \sum_{j = 1}^\infty \lvert x_j\rvert^p = \frac{1}{p\|x\|_{\ell_p}^p}\|x\|_{\ell_p^p} = \frac{1}{p}$$

and similarly

$$\sum_{j = 1}^n \frac{1}{q}\frac{\lvert y_j\rvert^q}{\|y\|_{\ell_q}^q} \le \frac{1}{q}$$